# Block exchange from sending mails to internal organization

Tags: email, exchange, exchangeonline

there is a very specific challenge I'd like solve and so far nothing worked.

Situation:
We have a rather large exchange environment with multiple domains (@domain-a.com, @@domain-b.com, @domain-c.com).
Domain-A and Domain-B are using our Exchange server.
Domain-C, however, is using Exchange Online. The AD users of Domain-C are required in our forest. I have an AAD Connect running for these users. There's no hybrid exchange configured. The proxy adresses for their exchange online mailboxes are defined in the ad user attributes (as it's the only way by ms)

Problem:
When a user from Domain-A or Domain-B sends an email to a user from Domain-C they get an NDR.

I think that's because exchange tries to deliver the mail inside the org since there are AD Users which proxy adresses match the domain of the recipient.

Is there a way to force exchange to use outbound mail flow?
I tried getting into transport rules and outbound connectors. Is that the right approach?
On which step of mail flow does exchange decides which mail is handled "internally or externally"?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the detailed error message of the NDR? Be sure to remove all sensitive information involved.
Is Domain-C added as an accepted domain in your Exchange server? If so, try removing it and see if there's any difference.